# Access DataStoreAPI with third-party app

Tags: opendata, ckan

I want to access the [CKAN DataStoreAPI](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/datastore-api.html) with ruby. And i have some questions. Is it possible to access the DataStoreAPI with ruby? I want to create, read and update resources in the datastore and i prefer ruby.

Answer (score 1):

As the CKAN API uses HTTP, you can access it with whatever language you prefer simply by hitting the correct URIs. For example, there are libraries for PHP (https://github.com/opencolorado/PHP-Wrapper-for-CKAN-API), and .NET (https://github.com/opencolorado/.NET-Wrapper-for-CKAN-API). They look abandoned, though.

Although I also prefer Ruby, unless you have a really good reason for using it, I recommend you to stick with Python. There're a few good libraries that would help a lot when using the API like https://github.com/open-data/ckanapi and https://github.com/dgraziotin/libckan. As far as I know, there's no library for CKAN in Ruby, so you'll have to build your own.